# BFS, trying to implement a method that find out the way between two words

Tags: methods, breadth-first-search

First of all, it's a school assignment, what I wanna do, is adding a method to the bfs that will track the way between two words, which also will be parameters. Currently its looking like this:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista=[]

    def put(self,x):
        self.lista.append(x)

    def get(self):
        if not len(self.lista)==0:
            return self.lista.pop(0)

    def isempty(self):
        if len(self.lista)==0:
            return True
        else:
            False

    def length(self):
        return len(self.lista)


    def dequeue(self):
        if not len(self.lista)==0:
            n=self.lista.pop(0)
            return n

    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.lista.insert(0,item)

class Word:
    def __init__(self,w,f=None):
        self.word=w
        self.parent=f

def hamta():
    ordlista=[]
    fil=open("labb9text.txt")
    ordlista=[]
    for line in fil.readlines():
        ordlista.append(line.strip())
    return ordlista

def setlista():
    ordlista=hamta()
    setlista=set()
    for a in ordlista:
        if a not in setlista:
            setlista.add(a)
    return setlista

def hittabarn(parent):
    mangd=setlista() 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children

def way(start,slut): 
    queue=Queue()
    queue.enqueue(start)
    visited=set()                       
    while not queue.isempty():
        vertex=queue.get()
        if vertex==slut:
            return True
        else:
            visited.add(vertex)
            s=hittabarn(start)
            for vertex in s:
                if vertex not in visited:
                    queue.put(vertex)
                else:
                    visited.add(vertex)
    return False
```

updated the code, this should work!

Comment: just realized that slut is an extremely bad parameter when posting this on an english site, to my defence, its "end" in swedish, hope that wont stop you if you got any idea for me...

Comment: You might want to translate your code then... And make sure it's minimal, as in [mcve].

Comment: ye, I can see that my code is "swenglish", im sorry for that, I realize it wasnt the best idea, hopefully most of you understand what I wanna do at least

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your post to improve it.

Comment: Did update the code a bit, as I mention above, still not working, but at least its doing something :)

Comment: this one is solved right now, got another question now :) Will post that on another thread

Comment: If you managed to solve your issue in a useful way, please self-answer your question so that future visitors may benefit from your findings! And again, could you please [edit] your post to make the code minimal (see what is a [mcve]) and free of Swedish-to-English confusion?

Comment: ye, will do that, just realized my function never return false... something mustve gone horribly wrong...